# Nested functions: Function outputting `undefined` when called

Tags: javascript

I have made an arrow function as below, nested in the `getdata` function, when I call the `getdata` function, it outputs `undefined`, what am I doing wrong?

```js
let person = {
    name: "Mario",
    age: 30,
    salary: 5555,
    getdata: function () {

        welcome = () => {
            return `hello: ${this.name} your age is ${this.salary}`
        };
    },
}

console.log(person.getdata())
```

Comment: you are not return anything from that funtion so of course its going to give you undefined

Comment: You don't return anything directly in `getdata`, the only return is inside the arrow function expression set to `welcome` which isn't a return for `getdata`

Answer (score 2):

I think you mean to do this.

```
let person = {
    name: "Mario",
    age: 30,
    salary: 5555,
    getdata:  () => {
            return `hello: ${this.name} your age is ${this.salary}`
        };
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer , but i'm practicing  on the nested function , so i'm trying to display the sentence by this way

Answer (score 0):

```
let person = {
    name: "Mario",
    age: 30,
    salary: 5555,
    getdata: function () {
        return {
        welcome: function() {
            return `hello: ${this.name} your age is ${this.salary}`

}
}
        
    },
}
```

this will return you the desired result:

```
person.getdata().welcome()
```

Comment: It looks to me like you want to return a function from a function. so you can use this approach. or you can directly return getdata() as shown in other answers

Answer (score 0):

Since `getData()` is just a function that defines another function but doesn't return anything, the return value from calling it is `undefined`. But, if you remove the nested function, and just return the data you want, you will get a return value:

```js
let person = {
    name: "Mario",
    age: 30,
    salary: 5555,
    getdata: function () {
        return  `hello: ${this.name} your age is ${this.salary}`
    },
}

console.log(person.getdata());
```

Answer (score 0):

you can't passing context in a static Object,
the best mode to solve your problem is by js class:

```js
class person {
  constructor(data) {
    this.info = data;
  }

  welcome(){
    return `hello: ${this.info.name} your age is ${this.info.age}`
  }

  getSalary(){
    return this.info.salary;
  }

  getAge(){
    return this.info.age;
  }

}

var mario = {
    name: "Mario",
    age: 30,
    salary: 5555,

}


var data = new person(mario);

console.log(data.welcome());
console.log(data.getSalary());
console.log(data.getAge());
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because `getdata()` isn't returning anything. It just has a nested function. If all you want is to return the contents of welcome, this is what you would put.

```
let person = {
    name: "Mario",
    age: 30,
    salary: 5555,
    getdata: function () {
          return `hello: ${this.name} your age is ${this.salary}`
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your getdata function doesn't return anything.
What you want is to create an object **person** that has a property **getdata**, which is a function that returns a nested object that also has a property **welcome** that is a function that returns a string.

I think what you're trying to achieve is the following:

```
let person = {
    name: "Mario",
    age: 30,
    salary: 5555,
    getdata: function () {
        return {
            welcome: () =>  `hello: ${this.name} your age is ${this.salary}`
        }
    }
}
```

So you can do:

```
console.log(person.getdata().welcome()) //"hello: Mario your age is 5555"
```